# Select particular column from Datatable and bind with Data GridView C#, Windows form Application

Tags: c#

I am saving some data in Data table `dt_Companies`.

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(" Select ID,Company_Name,Zip,City,Street" +
                         " From Companies " +
                         " WHERE ( " + strr + " ) ", conn);

sda.Fill(dt_Companies);
```

I know to show this data in data grid view `dataGridView_Companies`. I have to use this

```
dataGridView_Companies.DataSource = dt_Companies;
```

But I only want to select `Company_Name,Zip,City,Street` from data table `dt_Companies`. I need the `ID` field later on that's why I cannot skip it.

I am looking some thing like this:

```
dataGridView_Companies.DataSource = dt_Companies.Select("Company_Name","Zip","City","Street");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'd like to display columns `Company_Name,Zip,City,Street` and hide columns `ID` ? If so, after binding data, you can choose whether to hide column name `ID` from `DataGridView`. See [How to: Hide Columns in DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BoundField in your asp. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just bind the columns you want :

```
<columns>
    <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName"
            convertemptystringtonull="true"
            headertext="Customer Name"/>
     <asp:boundfield datafield="Zip"
            convertemptystringtonull="true"
            headertext="Zip"/>
     <asp:boundfield datafield="City"
            convertemptystringtonull="true"
            headertext="City"/>
     <asp:boundfield datafield="Street"
            convertemptystringtonull="true"
            headertext="Street"/>
</columns>
```